# NSTimer stops due to Game Center

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, xcode4.2

i am facing issue with `NStimer`, i am rotating my loading image using `NSTimer` and also i have implemented Game Center in my project. The issue is, when my game is loading, if GC popup appears on the screen, my game stucks in loading state and `NSTimer` never get invalidate

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use blocks instead of NSTimer ?

Something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                     CGAffineTransform  rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI);
                     self.transform = rotation;
} completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

Comment: Additionally you can set the repeat count to `CGFLOAT_MAX`.